# Is this chandelier installation safe?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, mounting

I've just bought and installed [this chandelier](https://eurofase.lightingnewyork.com/product/lighting/ceiling-lights/chandeliers/eurofase-paget-chandeliers-37192-013/1842367.html) in my home's entryway with a vaulted ceiling (>12' high). Based on the [spec sheet](https://eurofase.lightingnewyork.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-master-catalog-lny/default/dwebe140ad/brand/eur/assets/specsheet/37192-013.pdf), the **chandelier weighs 74lb**, most of which seems to be in the pendants.

The [installation instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh9fQ.jpg) (basically 1 page including a picture, a couple of arrows, and very few words) explicitly stated the following:

> This luminaire must be mounted or supported independently of an outlet box

The instructions and the accompanying hardware showed the chandelier would be supported by:

- 2 screws mounting it to the ceiling electric box
- 16 anchors + screws mounting it to the surrounding drywall

With great difficulty, a friend and I installed it this week, with some clever ways to avoid lifting the weight (mostly in the pendants) until the fixture was attached. While installing this, 3 of the anchors got pushed the other side of the ceiling, so it's only supported by the 2 mounting screws + 13 anchors / screws into the drywall.

[image]

It looks good so far, but I'm concerned whether it's safe to mount such a heavy fixture using only 2 screws on the ceiling box (which is metal, and presumably mounted to joists) + a bunch of drywall anchors.

Is this a common setup? Am I right to be concerned that it might fall and kill someone in the next few months / years? How are such fixtures normally mounted?

---

**Update**: this is the electric box that the fixture was attached to (photo was taken after attaching drywall anchors, but before mounting the fixture).

[image]

**Update 2**: here are the 3 steel cables that came with the fixture, attached to the metal disc. As you can see there are only a few inches of slack when it's attached, which are necessary to give me enough space to actually attach it.

[image]

**Update 3**: here is a pic of how the electric box is attached to framing in the attic. The box appears to be directly screwed into a 2x4, which appears to be nailed into the nearby joists.

[image]
[image]

**Update 4**: Final mounting. I replaced the existing metal box with a [stronger box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-1-1-2-in-Deep-15-3-cu-in-Ceiling-Fan-Box-with-Metal-Cover-CMB150/205383181) rated for heavy fans (mounted to the 2x4 behind it), attached the metal disc to it, and threaded a [lag screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-3-3-4-in-L-Zinc-Plated-Lag-Thread-Screw-Eye-806916/204273856) (rated for 100lb+) into the 2x4 through the middle hole. I attached the steel hooks onto this lag screw, but I feel that this is only a backup, since there's no tension on them after tightening the chandelier onto the metal disc.
[image]
[image]

Comment: As an aside, I have no idea what the person who wrote these instructions was smoking when they wrote "Estimated assembly time: 20 minutes"

Comment: Expecting drywall to hold that weight is stupid.  Something of that weight needs screw mounting to structural members of the house.  That many holes in a circle in drywall weakens the drywall too much.  It is the same easy practice of making big holes in something, drywall/concrete.  Be afraid, very afraid.

Comment: @crip659 It's also attached to the ceiling electrical box (which is metal and attached to joists), but for whatever reason they also required the anchors in a circle around it. Is the total weight - weight carried by the electrical box still too much for the drywall anchors?

Comment: Different types of boxes.  Fan rated boxes usually can handle the weight.  A regular light box screwed to the side of a joist maybe not.  For that weight and cost, I want good screws holding it to joists/wood members.

Comment: I have a kitchen cabinet that I thought I had screwed into the studs.  After about 20 years one day it fell down.  I missed some studs.  It was probably just a bit heavier(stuff in it) than your light and much cheaper.

Comment: @crip659 yikes. Okay I plan to go up to the attic and see how the box is attached to the joists. Thanks!

Comment: Wait what?   Is there an unfinished attic floor above this?  That will change everything.  So much speculation in my answer and most of the comments here .. all not necessary.  Add a picture from above to your question.  There are all kinds of mounting brackets for heavy chandeliers.

Comment: Yeah there's an unfinished attic above, just hard to reach (it's above a vaulted ceiling that isn't flat). I plan to go there today to confirm, and will post a pic after :)

Comment: Be careful climbing around on a vaulted ceiling. You could cause serious damage to the ceiling and even fall through.

Comment: I just looked at the instructions and I think you misrepresent them in the Question.  I'm going to add an answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to make the OP feel bad by writing this -- it's more to serve as a warning to future readers: those drywall plugs are absolute crap for this application. In the initial read, I'd somehow assumed these were toggles or something decent, which is still a bad idea, given the weight, but if this was my house and the chandelier was still up there, I'd be taking it down **immediately**.

Comment: FWIW these are some of the worst instructions I've ever seen (with almost no written instructions), especially for a product that's this important to mount correctly. I had interpreted them based on what was in the box as well. Having said that, per other answers and comments below, I plan to take this down today until I put up a new, stronger box.

Comment: The strength of the box is good. You do not need to take down the box. I think what you need to do is to feed those clips through those slots (or through other holes you make in the metal disc), around the metal electrical box and secure them to the 2x4 brace. That is if you want to follow the instructions. The cables should bear the load of the chandelier according to the instructions.

Comment: See EDIT 3 of my answer. The old 70 lb Hunter fans were hung from a single heavy hook threaded into the framing lumber behind the box. I used this 40 years ago to hang three Hunter fans and they are still there.

Comment: Kudos to @jay613 for reading the instructions and realizing that the chandelier MUST be suspended from thos three steel cables. In my EDIT 3 I describe one way to do this. Do not worry about the wood exposed by removing the knockout. If that bothers you you could leave the knockout in place and drill through that first with the size drill to hold the hook and then enlarge the hole in the metal box slightly to allow the threads in the hook free passage. I have just removed the 1/2" knockout in installing my Hunter fans. Connecting with those wago connectors will make a good connection:no fire

Comment: Use silicone or other thread lubricant on the threads of the hook, otherwise it will be too hard to screw in.

Answer (score 6):

I think you misread the instructions in a subtle but important way.  They do not say that you can use the ceiling box plus some drywall anchors.  They say you must not use the ceiling box *at all* to support this lamp.  The weight must primarily be supported by a special-purpose hanging bracket for heavy light fixtures.  It's shown in the instructions as a steel cable wrapped around a rod, which is one way to do it.

Presumably the steel cable is a component of the lamp ... please confirm that.

The instructions aren't clear but I believe the drywall anchors are to add stiffness and strength to the large metal disc, to help it support all the pendants.  That makes sense, it is a better approach than making the disc thicker and stronger, *and thereby heavier*.

The diagram shows a steel cable going through the back of the junction box and attached to a support bracket.

I've looked at a few ceiling fan brackets.  They are limited to 70 pounds.  You should not use them!  One of them (Hubbel) says it can be used by a 110 pound *light* (but not fan) so you maybe you could use that.  But as long as you are going out and buying a special bracket for this, you may as well buy one that's not borderline.

A cheap and safe way to do it is with a steel rod sitting on top of the joists.  Strut channel would be easiest because you can use the holes to fasten it to the tops of the joists, to fasten a junction box and to wrap the cable.

You can search for special-purpose heavy chandelier struts but they are just expensive steel bars.  You can buy [motorized ones](https://www.build.com/aladdin-light-lift-all200/s423851?uid=1022600&searchId=lOq3OSWtqB) that allow you easy access for cleaning.

You should make sure the ceiling joists are suitable for this.  Hopefully, 75 pounds spread across two joists should not be a problem even if the ceiling was not designed to do more than support the drywall.

Comment: I think you are correct. The support is supposed to be by the steel cable..

Comment: When you use a pipe to hold the steel cable how do you restrain the pipe from rotating due to the torque from the cable wrapped around it? You would want a circular cross section pipe or rod so that there is no cutting or chafing from a sharp edge.

Comment: @JimStewart I haven't thought this through in full detail.  Maybe there's a product opportunity.  Good questions.  I think most unistrut style bars are sufficiently rounded to not damage the cable.  But you could adapt components from hoisting or fishing suppliers to build a cable guide... or even attach a winch to the strut.

Comment: It does come with 3 small steel cables with hooks attached, but which were barely long enough to attach to the bottom of the metal disk (with a couple of inches of slack to give me space to attach it). I had assumed this was a way to get some quick relief from the weight while attaching it.

Comment: I don't know if the steel cables are long enough to go through an electric box and around a steel rod after. Also, I don't know of any listed electric boxes (for 120VAC) that are open at the back to allow the hooks through, since presumably that would go against their job of containing arcs, right?

Comment: The pic in the instructions indicates that the steel cable is long enough. Isn't there only one steel cable? You would just drill a hole perhaps 1/4" diameter in the center of the box. There are already holes shown in the pic but it is not in the center. The hooks I was talking about would not go through the box but along the outside and hook the edge of the box. (This is an idea that just came to me and experts would have to say if it could be done.)

Comment: What have you done with the steel cable?  Is there one steel cable or are there more than one?

Comment: Have you been able to look at the box from the attic?

Comment: There appears to be a "knock out" in the center of the box. You would pry that loose with a screwdriver and twist it off with pliers. That would give you a hole in the center of the box. If there is a wooden member over that you would drill a hole through that.

Comment: I assumed that the cables would go through the center of the box but maybe the cables go around the outside of the box and each cable is supposed to go around a separate pipe in the attic. How do these 3 cables attach to the chandelier? Presumablly in an equilateral triangle, if so how far apart are the attachment points on the fixture? 2 inches? 3 inches? . . .?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do297.jpg) are the 3 steel cables with hooks, which I attached to the metal disc. As you can see there are only a few inches of slack, which were needed to give me space to actually attach it. Even if I were to remove a knockout at the back of the box (not sure leaving it open is code compliant, but perhaps I can use a NM clamp and tighten it), I wouldn't have enough working space or slack to pull the steel cables to anything above the box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147004/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-peter).

Answer (score 4):

So far you have not provided enough information to determine the risk of failure.

You say there is a metal box, but what kind of metal box? What was the weight of the fixture that was mounted there before? This could be an indication of the holding capacity of this arrangement. Is the metal box supported on both sides (to two different joists)? Or is it supported only on one side to the side of the joist?

If it is it screwed to the bottom edge of a single joist it can be a secure mounting if the screws holding the box to the joist are rated for this AND if the screws holding the fixture to the box are rated for that. But if the fixture is held by two small diameter bolts to the small tabs at opposite sides, then this is not strong enough.

EDIT

Since you are able to examine the mounting of this metal box from the attic you will be able to better understand how the box is mounted. The best case would be that the box is securely mounted to a wooden member in the attic. The best mounting would be if the top of the box is securely screwed to a 2x4 or 2x6 in the attic edgeways or turned wide side down. A 1x4 might be strong enough but 2x lumber is much, much better. From the attic however you may not be able to see how the metal box is attached to the wooden member.

If in the attic you see that the box is attached to the side of a ceiling joist, then this box would probably not be able to support the load if the two tabs are used. There is still a way to use the box using long sprecial screws which go through the back of the box and into the wooden support.  . . . waiting on your report and pic of what you see in the attic.

EDIT 2

If the box is attached only to one side of a joist, the other side of the box could be supported by retrofit blocking.

Install a 2x4 as blocking between the joists right across the top of the metal box and attach to the sides of the two joists. Use Simpson Strong Tie corner fasteners with screws (nailing could damage ceiling drywall). Insert a metal rod with a small hook on the end (or better a strong nonmetal hook) between the box and the ceiling drywall and catch the bottom edge of the metal box. Tension by pulling up and fasten the shaft of the hook to the side of the 2x4 blocking. Do this on both sides of the 2x4 blocking. The box is now securely fastened to the framing on both sides.

The hook could be made out of a large nail 16d or so. Flatten the first inch of the sharp end and then bend the flattened end into a small hook. However, a longer rod would be easier to install. Fasten the shaft of the hook to the side of the 2x4 blocking with screws in pairs. A hook could be made from stiff perforated angle steel or perforated flat steel.

EDIT 3

You have very strong framing; it is enought to hold this chandelier. The chandelier MUST be suspended by the three steel cables. Here is how to do it:  In the center of the box is a knockout. Pry that out and twist it off to expose the 2x4" blocking above the steel box. Get a heavy screw in hook like those used for the old style Hunter 70 lb fans. Drill a hole vertically all the way through the 2x4 blocking. The diameter of this hole will be the correct size for the threads on the screw in hook and will be somthing like 1/4", 5/16" or 3/8" diameter depending on the diameter of the shaft inside the threads (not the outer dia of the threads). Screw in the hook and hang the steel cables from that.

Something like this but lighter rating in 100 lb to 200 lb range.
[https://www.amazon.com/BeneLabel-Heavy-Duty-Swing-Hangers/dp/B07XYZMGQ6/ref=asc_df_B07XYZMGQ6/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=416882833842&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16422389901641170286&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=pla-900946197839&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=92049666137&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=416882833842&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16422389901641170286&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=pla-900946197839](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XYZMGQ6)

EDIT 4

There is another way to support a chandelier that uses a *bolt* rather than a screw. The use of a lag screw hook enables installation completely from the living space below, but for really heavy loads a lag screw is not aceptable. The wood may not have sufficient pull out resistance.

In that case the hook has machine screw threads (not wood threads). A large nut over a large washer holds the hook on top (and usually a smaller washer and a nut on the underside). This is a lot stronger than a lag screw.

But this requires access to the 2x4 blocking in the space above. In this case the hole is drilled slightly larger that the threads of the hook so that the shaft goes through the hole with no resistance. This is more trouble to install but allows a lot of adjustment. I can imagine a special washer and nut combination which would be positioned over the predrilled hole in the blocking and fastened to the blocking so that, once fastened, no further access to the attic would be needed.

An eyebolt might not be necessary in this case but if you wanted to do the ultimate installation, then a 3/8" x 6" or 3/8" x 4.5" eyebolt might be the right solution. https://e-rigging.com/products/galvanized-drop-forged-regular-eye-bolts?variant=39745724710985 You would get a suitable washer for the top and another nut and washer for the inside of the box. Possibly you would not need a nut and washer inside the box, but it might be a useful addition.

Note that you must check that the diameter of the material of the ring is not too large for the clips (carabiners) on the ends of the cables. It could be that 3/8" is too large.

EDIT 5
Looking at your last pic (showing the eye screw with cables attached) it appears to me that set screws can be used to shorten these cables. Loosen the two set screws, then pull the end of the wire through the fitting to the right length, then retighten the set screws.

The "safety" cable can be left a little loose because it only would come into play if the three primary cables would fail. You might need to get another carabiner clip for the safety cable.

Comment: I believe the screws from fixture to metal box are indeed small in diameter and going to the two small tabs in the box. But this is the kit that came with the fixture -- shouldn't they be rated for this fixture's weight?

Comment: AFIK those small tabs are only there to attach a cover to the box or to attach lightweight fixtures. Metal ceiling boxes that are designed to hang a heavy fixture such as a heavy ceiling fan or a heavy chandelier have two robust "nuts"  or threaded tubes that are attached to the metal box in a fashion that can support a heavy weight. The threads in this tube are at least 1/2 inch depth. The little tabs on the outside are so thin (maybe 1/8 inch? less?) that they do not have enough length of threads to support a heavy weight.

Comment: Some boxes that are designed for hanging heavy fans may have fairly small screws that would fit your description of the metal box you have. But the box you have could also be an ordinary box not designed for a heavy chandelier. Did you take a picture of the box before you hung the fixture?

Comment: Here's a picture I took of the box after before mounting the fixture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGHoh.jpg

Comment: From the info you have given so far we cannot tell whether your installation meets standards or not. I don't want to be alarmist. It is quite possible that your installation is fully adequate, but it is also possible that it is not up to standard. Note that even a substandard mounting might never actually fall but given the consequences if it did fall this is not a case where substandard is acceptable.

Comment: AFIK that is an ordinary ceiling box and is not rated to suspend a heavy chandelier _from those tabs_. At this point much more experienced people need to get in on this.

Comment: Damn, I had assumed it was suitable given the previous chandelier hanging from there. Though to be fair, the previous chandelier was much lighter. I guess the fix would be to replace that box entirely with a more heavy duty one, and ensure it's attached appropriately to the joists?

Comment: I have hung about 10 ceiling fans of two different types: 70 lb old Hunter oil bath fans and newer, lighter Hunter fans. I believe that an expert would tell you to take this chandelier down and rehang it with a stronger mounting.. This can be done entirely from the living space.

Comment: Contact the building inspection entity for your area and ask them about it. They might say, "Technically this does not meet standards, but don't lose any sleep." Or they might say, "Completely unacceptable and a real risk of injury, likely fatal."

Comment: [This box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-15-3-cu-in-Remodel-Construction-Ceiling-Fan-Brace-with-1-1-2-in-Box-CMB150-OB/205383178) seems rated for 70lb fans (or 150lb lights on 16" joists) and claims to be installable entirely from the ceiling, though I wonder if the current drywall hole is big enough for that. Anyway, I'll see when I get to installing it. Thanks!

Comment: Follow the instructions and that brace will go through that hole as it is.  That is what it is designed to do. But the current box might possibly be OK to use as it is, depending on what the joists look like and what hardware came with the chandelier or what you can get.  Take the chandelier down carefully and examine the arrangement of joists and how the box is attached to the joists. I am going to explain more in my answer.

Comment: Note that many houses have ceiling joists on 24 inch centers. A braced box like the one you have pictured will accomodate from 16" to 24" joist spacing center to center.

Comment: If attic access is rough, those fan rated boxes are actually really easy to put up through a standard size hole.

Comment: The hook idea seems promising. I just bought this 1/4" diameter x 3-3/4" L [Screw eye lag thread](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-3-3-4-in-L-Zinc-Plated-Lag-Thread-Screw-Eye-806916/204273856) bolts from home depot, which are supposed to carry 120lb each. If it's easy to remove the KO I will, otherwise will just drill through it to the 2x4 to attach this thing. For a 1/4" thread, should I pre-drill with a 1/4" bit?

Comment: The drill size MUST be smaller than the outer diameter of the threads. Normally you size the drill to be equal to the underlying shaft. I would say go a little smaller rther than larger for a lag screw into soft wood like a 2x4. But don't go so small as to split the 2x4!! I use wax thread lubricant. Note that for a 2x4 width down there is only 1.5 inches of wood. Drill all the way through and out the other side. The loop hook you have bought may be too short or may be OK. Personally I would use a longer and heavier one.

Comment: There is another way to support a chandelier that uses an eye *bolt* rather than an eye *screw*. See EDIT 4 of my answer.

Comment: Is the chandelier hanging from a level ceiling or is the ceiling sloped *where the chandelier is hanging*?

Comment: I went with a modified version of your edit 4. I replaced the existing metal box with a stronger one (linked in my original post) rated for heavy fans (mounted to the 2x4 behind it), attached the metal disc to it, and threaded that lag screw (rated for 100lb+) into the 2x4 through the middle hole. I attached the steel hooks onto this lag screw, but I feel that this is only a backup, since there's no tension on the steel cable after tightening the chandelier onto the metal disc. I don't see any way to leave tension on those cables while mounting the chandelier to the right height.

Comment: Not being there I cannot see the details. Your installation sounds sufficient, but the cables are supposed to be taut and carrying the load. Is the length of the cables fixed, set by the end fittings crimped on?

Comment: Maybe there is supposed to be a variable gap between the metal disc affixed to the ceiling and the top of the chandelier.

Comment: So you actually have FOUR steel cables with the fourth being heavier than the other 3 and labeled "safety cable". I think you must have gotten incomplete instructions. I think the lengths of all the cables is adjustable with a set screw. These could be shortened.

Comment: Looking at your last pic (showing the eye screw with cables attached) it appears to me that set screws can be used to shorten these cables. Loosen the two set screws, then pull the end of the wire through the fitting to the right length, then retighten the set screws. The "safety" cable can be left a little loose because it only would come into play if the three cables would fail. You might need to get another carabiner clip for the safety cable.

Comment: There are two large holes in the thin metal plate. Probably the instructions were that the three primary suspension cables were to be hung from the primary eye screw in the center of the electrical box. These cables would be taut and carrying the load of the chandelier. Then the "safety cable" would be attached to another hook which would be screwed into a robust frame member outside the electrical box at the location of the second large hole. The safety cable would be slightly untensioned and so bearing no load unless the primary hook would fail. The chandelier would have a backup hold.

Comment: The metal plate would have had to be installed so that the off center hole was under the wooden frame member. If it is not, then drill a 3/8" or 1/2" hole in the thin metal plate under the 2x4 above the box. Then drill a hole for another hook and install a hook there for the safety cable. Adjust the length of the safety cable so it is very slightly slack. Unless there is a carabiner you might have to bend out the eye hook slightly to get the safety cable over the eye bolt.

Comment: What size hole did you drill for the 1/4" eye screw you used? How hard was it to screw in the eye screw? Very easy? Medium? Hard to screw in? Did you use thread lubricant?